# Можно ли пройти проверку Google Play до релиза

Tags: android, google-play

Приложение готово на 99% хотим пока идет проверка приложения гугл плеем допилить остальное и выкатить обновлением, что-бы не тратить время т.к его просто не осталось. Желательно что-бы страница приложения была недоступна на время после проверки пока не выкатим обнову, как такое сделать? Опубликует ли гугл плей приложение если в нем не функционирует только маленькая часть?

Comment: Можно. Сначала делается закрытая версия приложения, после эту версию можно выкатить в рабочую.

Comment: Однако, не стоит рассчитывать на прогнозируемые сроки проверки приложения. Оно может и за пару часов провериться для первоначального релиза, а потом, когда вы доделаете - может пару недель обновление на проверке висеть. А потом вообще могут забанить автоматически из-за сбоя робота-модератора. И эти 3 проблемы у вас могут в любой последовательности вылезти. Засим вы можете попробовать, но будьте заранее готовы у возможным проблемам.